# Add a UINavigationController wrap the FlutterController crash

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, navigation

I try to add a UINavigationController wrap the FlutterController(the initial view controller) in a flutter project, but it crash when excute
`GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is the UINavigationController be use to `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)`
so it crash.
How can I make it work?